# Program does not work with newline

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int force(int mass, int acce);

int main ()
{
    int mass;
    int acce;

    scanf( "%d", &mass );
    scanf( "%d", &acce );
    printf("The force is %d n\ ",force(mass ,acce));
}

int force(int mass, int acce)
{
    return mass * acce;
}
```

I am trying to run a simple program in C. When I run the above program I find the following error:

```
Force.c:12:11: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\040'.
```

The is not clear to me. Would you please give an explanation.

Comment: The force is so crushing that your indentation is caving in to the left.

Comment: what does this have to do with a `struct`?

Comment: I didn't even notice there weren't any structs in the code :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put `n\` in your `printf` statement. I think you meant `\n`. This is called an escape character (this one is a newline). Yours was trying to do the escape character `'\ '`. If you want to print a single backslash, use `\\`.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `n\` with `\n`, if you truely want n then slash, put `n\\`, otherwise `\n` creates a newline character.